# How to make two docker containers running on the same local communicate?

Tags: api, docker-compose

I'm running to APIs through docker-compose on linux. I tried to pass them IPs that docker containers have, i checked with: docker inspect . They are on the same (docker)network. Should this work, and I'm mistaken, or is there simpler way to set each their address in some easy way. I went through docker docs, but nothing seems to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start docker containers and expose ports from each container, the default IP would be `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`

So, containers can communicate via: `localhost:<port_of_other_container>`

If it doesn't work try with `ifconfig -> en0 -> inet address` instead of localhost.